# Dynamic allocation of an array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, memory-management

I've a trouble about this *syntax*.
The problem says:
*calculate the histogram of occurrences of names using an array of structures allocated dynamically at runtime*
I solved it in this way (I preferred to use pastebin to avoid to paste too much code here):
**main.cpp** http://pastebin.com/TD6Y2Acf 
**dinalloc.cpp** http://pastebin.com/93eM9EdL 
**dinalloc.h** http://pastebin.com/bUX7TxTs 
It works, but I cannot understand why... 
I declared a struct called `hi` and an array of this structures called `vet`. When, in the *dinalloc.cpp* I declare the function parameters, I have to wrote `hi *vet`. In this way, it means that I'm saying to the function to expect a pointer to an `hi` structure, or not? Instead, when I call the function, I give `vet` as parameter, that is an **array** of `hi` structures.
How it's possible that this code works?

P.S. Any advice about my code-writing method is welcome.

Comment: "the problem says" - homework?

Comment: Nope. It's an exercise that I tried to do after the lesson on dynamic allocation of the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. Actually array is a pointer to it's first element, and that's what you've got from your new operator.

Even if you had a code like

```
const int n = 5;
hi vet[n];
// ...
printHistogram(vet, n);
```

It is still correct. According to 4.2 paragraph of the c++ standart,

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: @PraZuBeR
So, it's not important that hi is a structure? It's enough that I declare the pointer to hi and then give tu the function (when i call) a pointer to an array? Or it's the array that is a generic pointer to a memory area?

Comment: @unNaturhal It is important that hi is the type that function expects. But it's not important how hi was declared: new hi; or new hi[n]; the function will work correctly in both cases, just don't forget in the first case to set n to one when you'll be passing it to the function.

Comment: @PraZuBeR Mmmh, but hi is the type expected by the function. What I pass to the function is vet. Writing hi *vey = new hi[n]; I'm declaring vet as a pointer to the hi type, or not?

Comment: @unNaturhal Yes. In this case, vey is a pointer to the first hi structure in a row. vey is pointing to the first hi structure, vey+1 is pointing to the second hi structure, ... , vey+n-1 is pointing to the last hi structure.

Comment: @PraZuBeR Aaaah! Understood! Thank you very much for your explanation! :)
P.S. Could you link me the C++ standard where did you get the 4.2 paragraph?

Comment: @unNaturhal Sure. [C++ Standart (draft 3242)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)